# Pergunta sobre como abreviar milhares/milhões/bilhões em um programa. É aceita no SOPT?

Tags: debate

Boa noite,

Necessito de ajuda para abreviar *milhares/milhões/bilhões* corretamente para países lusófonos.

A pergunta é mais sobre **gramática** do que programação, porém vou utilizá-lo em um **aplicativo para a web**. Posso postar sem nenhum problema no Stack Overflow em Português?

Se sim, a tag correta seria **contexto**?

Comment: Esse é um caso "borderline", mas pergunte! A(s) tag(s) apropriada(s) seria(m) "usabilidade", "localização" e/ou "interface-de-usuário". Poste também nos comentários um link pra **esta** pergunta, pra evitar aborrecimentos; algo como: "Se acha que essa pergunta não é on topic, \[dê sua opinião no meta\](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1105)"

Answer (score 4):

Perguntar diretamente "Como abreviar a palavra 'milhões'?" pode não dar bom resultado, pois está claro que não há nada de programação na pergunta. Mas você pode puxar para o lado do desenvolvimento de software e da interface de usuário, que é on-topic.

Pergunte, por exemplo, sobre como passar a ideia de "milhões/bilhões" ao usuário usando um espaço limitado. Pode inclusive surgir soluções que você não esperava, como usar algum tipo de ícone ou outra coisa que não "mi/bi".

O truque está em escrever do jeito certo para manter a pergunta contextualizada.

Answer (score 2):

Se é uma dúvida puramente gramatical, eu votaria por descontextualizada pois não é sobre programação.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que para contextualizar a pergunta, o ideal seria juntar gramática e [**Internacionalização de Software : L10n**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(software)). Ou então, tentar conseguir *feedback* de outros usuários sobre a dúvida gramatical na [sala de bate-papo do SOPT](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).